# CSS font-family inherit for headings

Tags: css, inheritance

If I want to use font family used in the body for headings, I can simply use inherit property but what if I want to use different font family other than that used in the body for headings?

For example, I can make it like:

```
h1 { font-family:'Noto Sans', sans-serif; }
h2 { font-family:'Noto Sans', sans-serif; }
h3 { font-family:'Noto Sans', sans-serif; }
h4 { font-family:'Noto Sans', sans-serif; }
h5 { font-family:'Noto Sans', sans-serif; }
h6 { font-family:'Noto Sans', sans-serif; }
```

but I want to know parent-child hierarchy of heading tags (if there is one)
to see if I can do this and avoid duplicates.

```
h1 { font-family:'Noto Sans', sans-serif; }
h2 { font-family:inherit; }
h3 { font-family:inherit; }
h4 { font-family:inherit; }
h5 { font-family:inherit; }
h6 { font-family:inherit; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, all the heading tags are separate elements and don't follow any type of inheritance rules like you've listed.

What you can do is try and setting all of the `font-family` settings all at once like using a comma-separated list.

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This is as nice as using inherit property for smaller block of codes. I can't believe I couldn't come up with this...

Comment: ".. all the heading tags are separate elements... " - Base on what you said that? The heading fonts are apply font family from the parent.